# Select rows from yesterday's date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query function that selects all rows from the previous days. However, I need it to only select the rows with yesterdays date but am unsure how to include just the previous day.

My current query is:

```
SELECT pdate FROM table 1
WHERE pdate < Date(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would imagine it would look something like this, which has the advantage of using indexes (if you have them implemented)

```
SELECT pdate FROM table 1
WHERE pdate >= Date(NOW()) - INTERVAL 1 DAY
AND pdate < Date(NOW())
```

Comment: I actually just tried this as a solution, it seems to do the trick.

Comment: Will this look for dates from yesterday and today, since DATE(NOW()) + INTERVAL 1 DAY returns tomorrow?

Comment: @McAdam331 You're right, I meant to remove the + INTERVAL 1 DAY

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `DATE_SUB()` function to get yesterday's date, and then use a `WHERE` clause condition to look for just that date, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable
WHERE DATE(pDate) = DATE_SUB(pDate, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Here is a list of [MySQL's Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html) which may help you.

---

NOTE: This will work, but because you are using a function on the pDate column in the where clause this will not be able to take advantage of any indexes you have (see comments below). Brian Driscoll has given an answer that will work better. I am choosing to leave this answer because while it is less efficient, I believe it is more readable as the where clause is very explicit in what it is checking and is slightly more readable. Whether or not the trade off is worth it here is up to the developer.

Comment: This will work but will toss indexes out the window, which might not be a good thing.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll thanks for letting me know. Is there a way to use this solution and take advantage of indexes? I suspect not, because it's the first `DATE(pDate)` that would void it of indexes, isn't it?

Comment: Yep, you're exactly right, DATE(pdate) will hose the indexes.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll cool, I'm going to leave the answer but added a little disclaimer about the efficiency.